# Using AJAX in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, search

I'm finished with doing a search application in Ruby on rails. But now I need to use AJAX into to it, so that the search action doesn't reload a new page.This is application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){
  $("#autoc").submit(function(){
    $.get(this.action, $this.serialize(),null,"script")
    return false;
  });
});
```

This is view page:

```
<h4>Results for your search.</h4>
<br>
<br>

<div id="container">
  <% if !(@results.nil?)%>

    <% for prod in @results %>
      <div class="product">
        <div class="image"><%= image_tag(prod.image, :alt => "logo", :size => "75x75") %>       </div>
    <div class="name"><h3> <%= prod.name %> </h3></div>
    <div class="price"><h5>Old Price:</h5><%= prod.maxprice%></div>
        <div class="price"> <h5>New Price:</h5><%= (prod.maxprice)-(prod.maxprice * prod.discount / 100) %></div>   
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And this is my controllers code:

```
def index
  @init = Sunspot.search(Clothes) do
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 24
    order_by :maxprice
  end
  @first = @init.results
end

def show
  if params[:name] == ""
    @search = []
  else
    @search = Sunspot.search(Clothes) do
      fulltext params[:name]
      paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 24
      order_by :maxprice
    end
    @results = @search.results
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Enter something!"
end

def autocomplete
  list=[] 
   @res = Clothes.search do
    fulltext params[:term]
    paginate :page => 1, :per_page => 100
    order_by :maxprice
  end
  @rest = @res.results
  @rest.each do |brand|
    list << {"label"=>brand.name, "value"=>brand.name, "id"=>brand.id}
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json{render :json=>list.to_json, :layout=>false}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `remote: true` to enable ajax.

More reference is available [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html).

Comment: probably the simplest way to do it, but you should include more detail in the actual answer, instead of linking to an external page.

Answer (score 0):

**Response**

You need to append your results to your page

Ajax works by sending a request on your behalf, and allowing you to use the returned response on your page. I'd do this:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("#autoc").on("submit", function() {
    $.ajax({
         url: $(this).action,
         data: $(this).serialize(),
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(data) {
              $("#container").html(data);
         },
         error: function(data) {
             alert("Sorry, there was an error!");
         }
    });
});
```

This is, of course, if your controller action code checks out!

Comment: I did what you said. But there's still a query string in the url.

Comment: I've set 'remote :true' in my form tag!

Comment: Query string in the URL is from the `GET` method. If you want to just send pure data (no query string), you'll need to use the `POST` method. You can see an example on one of our development sites: http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk